# change class name using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, smarty

I'd like to change the class of a certain div. I am doing a load-more function and everytime I load new content I have to update it with the correct information. So, I decided to make this function that selects my .status class. I want to add `answered-accepted` or `answer-selected`.

```
function updateSolvedStatus(viewsCount, object) {
    if(object.solved_date) {
        viewsCount.attr('class', 'status answered-accepted');
        console.log(viewsCount);
    } else {
        viewsCount.attr('class', 'status answer-selected');
    }
}
```

This is my html `div` with Smarty , a template for PHP. It is quiet simple. I want my class to be accepted if solved_date isnt null and if not null I want my class to be `answer_selected`.

Is there any way to change my class name using this method?

```
<div {if $question['solved_date']}
            class="status answered-accepted"
        {else}
            class="status answer-selected"
        {/if}
                title="one of the answers was accepted as the correct answer">
            <div class="answers-count">
                <span title="{$question['answers_count']} answer">{$question['answers_count']}</span></div>
            <div>answer</div>
        </div>
```

Comment: In your `updateSolvedStatus` function are you passing dom element as `viewsCount`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand well your question. I assume you are aware what code runs in server-side and what code runs in client-side. 
You can use something like this to change the class of an element via Javascript:

```
<!--HTML-->
<div id=MyElement>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className = "status answered-accepted";
```

Answer (score 0):

My question does not make sense. The problem isn't coming from what I report. It is a CSS problem. You can just delete this and sorry for wasting your time.

Kinds regards